# when I had build apk in Android Studio ,my apk automatic add that [ .so ][ libnative.so , libbarhopper_v2.so ]

Tags: android

```
  ndk{
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
        }
```

that is I already had add it ,but in my apk,always had add two .so file that I don't need it .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vboPs.png)

Comment: I had think all day ,and search for it ,but the answer in Internet is show me to add ndk{ abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a" } in my build.gradle.but I had already add it in my build.gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need file .so to run your app. It is dynamic libraries. As your pic, you using JNI and NDK compiles the C/C++ code into .so files.

armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a is [Android ABI](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html) u can choose one or more as user platform

Comment: could your describe the answer more and more clearly,I had only ndk{ abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"}in my build.gradle,but it not get successful,also had appear ten .so,it's not eight .so. Oh my God ,How can I do ,but I will not give it up

Comment: Sr, I miss understand your question. I think you are wonder about .so file but seem your trouble is can not run your program?  Find the file name Application.mk and add the line APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a.  I think you need describe more about your trouble

Comment: yes ,you're right . your means is currently get what I had do .

Comment: you're right. I first should run my program, but it's seem not useful. my App is always had appear that sentence [ Error: Not enough storage space to install required resources ] . I search fo it ,know it is maybe the il2cpp.so questions ,and the I had looking at the first can running the APP, in the apk,only had eight .so file and that is the obvious differently between the running APP and the false App